# Replace non-standard URL patterns inside text file using unix or python

Tags: regex, linux, bash, unix, sed

I have a text file with many lines, that contains URLs that look like this:

`http // t . co / gjut7iu89o`

I want to label this whole portion to URL

The URL portion is in between text so i can't just remove everything after http, which I tried here:

`sed -i 's/\https.*/URL/' filename`

That is removing everything after the url, which is not what I want.

I tried with `sed` re but can't get the logic to remove this pattern inside text file

Comment: What is the desired output ?  Can you please edit the question.  Thanks

Comment: Is this what you're looking for: `'http // t . co / gjut7iu89o'.replace(' ', '').replace('//', '://').replace('p:', 'ps:')`?

Answer (score 0):

You have a text file that looks like this:

```
Some text hello http // t . co / lorem this is
a text file with http // t . co / ipsum many lines
and urls http // t . co / whatever everywhere
```

You want it to look like this:

```
Some text hello URL this is
a text file with URL many lines
and urls URL everywhere
```

If my understanding is correct, and if these are all t.co links or only have one word after the final `/`, you could restrict the match to one word after the final `/`.  This will work with `GNU` sed with the `-r` option

```regex
sed -r -i 's/https?.*\/\s*\w*/URL/g' filename
```

The regex part, for use with another tool is:

```regex
/https?.*\/\s*\w*/
```

- `s?`: Optional s
- `.*\/`: everything up to an escaped /
- `\s*`: any number of consecutive spaces (or none)
- `\w*`: one or more consecutive regex word characters

That will produce the desired output as above

Comment: hi! would like to confirm but shouldn't the flag be `-r` (lowercase) instead of `-R`?

Comment: @nigel thanks alot.  Indeed.  That's what I thought too, until checking it to be sure.  Only just now as you mentioned it I looked a little deeper and saw that my `sed` was currently linked to supersed.  Updating now